# Multiple Language support in Google form

Tags: php, internationalization, google-forms

Using Google form i created a survey form and collects data to the spreadsheet. I would like to use this form in different languages(Internationalisation). Google form support multiple language in one form?
any methods for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

google forms do not support this. there is a 3rd party tool to customize the form further but i doubt it can accomplish it. http://sneakysheep.com/google-docs-form-tool-version-2/

Answer (score 0):

This is no ideal, but if you just want one other language, you can use the "Help Text" for the other language.